# FileNotFoundError despite image being in correct location

Tags: python

Very much a python newbie, using mac. I am having difficulty importing a Tiff image that is saved on my Desktop, and I do not know how to import it. I have double-checked that it is under the correct user and saved under Desktop, but I have not been able to produce the image. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what appears when I run the coding:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```
#part that is not working
image =r"c:\Users\kihyeon\Desktop\3T3_01.tif"
merge = img_as_float(mpimg.imread(image))
```

```
#show the image to test that it imported properly
plt.figure(figsize=(20,3))
plt.imshow(merge, cmap='green', interpolation='nearest') 
plt.show()
```

I imported these packages beforehand.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
```

Comment: In mac, there is no C:. kindly validate your path once again

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You're on a Mac so the path will be something more like:

```
image = r'/Users/kihyeon/Desktop/3T3_01.tif'
```

`C:\...` is for Windows only.